Can't make sense of this step while self-studying greens function
so I was self-studying green functions from Mary L Boas' MMP book and couldn't make sense of this step where she finds the difference in change of the associated greens function.

My main querie is about the last step and how the author equated the first term with the 1 on the RHS. I can make sense of the integral of the greens function (2nd term) going to zero as epsilon approaches 0 but shudnt the derivative of the greens function also approach zero as it also has a limit of epsilon imposed on it?

Aren't you integrating the delta function exactly on the spike at $x'$?

@Claudio yes but thats not really possible cuz theres a spike at x'. However, it is possible to find the change in G' before and after x', which is exactly what the first term is. Just understood this after the answer given below.

That would only be true if $G(x)$ were a smooth function. When it's not, its derivative $G'$ is discontinuous by definition, hence, the left and right limits (to the point of discontinuity) need not coincide.
